# Tesseract not recognize single number

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract

I'm using tesseract with c++. It recognize almost all number but in some case it not recognize.

I'm using digits_comma.traineddata from this link: https://github.com/Shreeshrii/tessdata_shreetest

This image tesseract return '2':

[image]

But this image tesseract return '':

[image]

I'm using tesseract 5.0.0. Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: Maybe your classification could benefit from cleaning up the blobs a little bit. Hard to know without any code to give you any pointers.

Comment: Looks like you need the clean your image from blobs(noise), you can have a look at [here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) which they suggesting about preprocessing

Comment: @eldesgraciado hardly to describe all code. But the point it i have 2 image like above and I put it in tesseract and result make me very confused

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk It there another solution without remove noise ?

Comment: @NightRider Removing noise is a problem ? Not coming to my mind another solution, tesseract is a big engine, if you dig in to its documentation you may find another way inside

Comment: It would be more helpful if you supplied a larger image showing more of what you are starting with. But there are many questions on stackoverflow on how to clean up images for OCR. Since this question has opencv tag, you should investigate thresholding. The [python thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) tutorial is really good and shows most of the important functions.